# How to read TimeoutStartSec value in systemD configuration from Application via Dbus interfaces

Tags: systemd

In my service configuration TimeoutStartSec == 100s.
According to man page.. my Application need to notify to systemD sd_notify(READY=1) during <100s. If not service is put into failed state.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
But in case of i want to do something ( eg just print out some log said : startup is not done in time ) . before my service is actually set to failed state .
Is there any change to do that...
My idea is create a timer which have same value with TimeoutStartSec == xx s
then i can manage to do something before timer expired.
But the question is TimeoutStartSec == xx is dynamicaly configured by user - in my project.. 
So i would expect some Dbus interface which will offer to read TimeoutStartSec from my application...
I checked 
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/
but did not found a corresponding property.

I am using systemD on Linux which freely use systemD Dbus interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution .
SystemD actually provide that info

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 --print-reply /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ServiceName_2eservice \
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:org.freedesktop.systemd1.Service string:TimeoutStartUSec
```

Note: your name of service need to modify to get exactly object path ServiceName.service adapt to ServiceName_2eservice